# MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm getting this error when I try to connect my app(nodejs) to mongodb. I really appreciate your help here.

```
MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
    at parseSrvConnectionString (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\uri_parser.js:41:21)
    at parseConnectionString (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\uri_parser.js:509:12)
    at connect (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:195:3)
    at connectOp (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:284:3)
    at executeOperation (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:416:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:175:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:341:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\NodeAPI\server.js:12:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

My code:

db.js

```
 module.exports = {
uri : "mongodb+srv://mithun:*******@cluster0-s089x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"}
```

==================================================================

node_route.js

```
 module.exports = function(app, db){
app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    const note = {text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title};
    db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, results) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({'error': 'An error has occured'});
        } else {
            res.send(result.ops[0]);
        }
    });
 });
 };
```

=======================================================================
index.js

```
 const noteRoutes = require('./note_route');
 module.exports = function(app, db){
 noteRoutes(app, db);
}
```

=========================================================================
server.js

```
       const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  MongoClient.connect(db.uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, database) => 
  {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
     require('./app/routes')(app, database);
      app.listen(port, () => {
           console.log("We are live on " +port);
  });
 });
```

===========================================================================

```
module.exports = {
uri : "mongodb+srv://mithun:m3Thun#47@cluster0-s089x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&ssl=false"
```

}

I've tried with ssl= false but the error remains same.

Comment: Please paste your code you're using to connect to mongo

Comment: The error seems to suggest that your URI variable does not contain a valid connection string (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples). Are you sure this variable contains a valid connection string?

Comment: @patricK,@Adam Harrison... Any idea on this issue.

Comment: removing the +srv after mongodb should be a quick fix

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Solution-1:** If you are using any special character in your password you need to encode the particular character as `%+ASCII_code_of_the_character` below link explains everything.
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password

**Solution-2:**
Click on auto-generate password and paste it into the connection string, it will work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. Thank you for helping community.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words @MrMegamind, do upvote,  so that others can also benefit from  it

Comment: If you are using any special character in your password you need to encode the particular character as  '%+ASCII_code_of_the_character' below link explains everything

"https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password"

Comment: That was actually the problem! @Priyom saha

Comment: thank you, this worked for me. maybe some characters aren't allowed in password. that might be the issue here

Answer (score 139):

Ensure special characters in your password are encoded. For example if your password contains '#' you should replace the literal '#' character with '%23' where 23 is the hex code for '#' see: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password

Comment: I did a quick google search and came up with this handy tool to help encode https://www.urlencoder.org. Worked like a charm for me!

Comment: Can't believe it was this easy, Had an "@" in the password, used @JoeMcLean suggested website and worked like charm.

Answer (score 19):

You might have *special characters* in your **password** string.

E.g. If your password was - `password!#`, `!#` are *special characters*, they would have to be rewritten as `%23%21`. Thus, your connection string password should be `password%23%21`.

For more information - [MongoDB](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password), [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/)

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache, thank you @Bilbo

Answer (score 19):

Convert the special characters (`: / ? # [ ] @`) in your `password` or `username` to percentange characters i.e

1. `@` = `%40`
2. `'` = `%27`
3. `!` = `%21`
4. [others](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

e.g.  `p@ssw0rd'9'!` becomes `p%40ssw0rd%279%27%21`

Comment: This one helped me.

Answer (score 11):

use '%23' instead of # in your password
and

`mongoURI =  "mongodb+srv://username:password@devconnector.jpokp.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

`mongoose .connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true }) .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected")) .catch((err) => console.log(err));`

Answer (score 5):

> Use of the +srv connection string modifier automatically sets the ssl
>   option to true for the connection. You can override this behavior by
>   explicitly setting the ssl option to false with ssl=false in the query
>   string.

May it can be a ssl problem? Try with no ssl:  `ssl=false`

Comment: module.exports = {
uri : "mongodb+srv://mithun:********@cluster0-s089x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&ssl=false"

Comment: @mithun47varghesevarghese_Jr  Hi,, did you solve this issue,, please share yur solution

Comment: That kind of worked. Instead of adding `ssl=false`, I removed `+srv`.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs because if you use some of the **special characters in your passwords**
like: `/ ? # [ ] @`

1. Now you have to convert your **password to a percentage encoding** password so for that put,

`@ = %40` (put %40 instead of @) 
`? = %3F`

`# = %23`

`[ = %5B`

`] = %5D` 
if some special character doesn't find here use below link.

2. Just put your password and get the percentage encoded password: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 5):

> **If the username or password includes the following characters:**

```
: **/ ? # [ ] @**
```

those characters must be converted using
percent encoding

You can convert using this site-

> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

I saw your MONGO_URI password contains **#** symbole which need to encode to **%23**

```
module.exports = {
uri : "mongodb+srv://mithun:m3Thun%2347@cluster0-s089x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&ssl=false"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this problem.

In my case, I was using `npm dotenv` package to get the username the password from a `.env` file.

When I logged the values from the `.env` file, I noticed it was not retrieving the password correctly.

It could be an issue with either the username or password.

Comment: I am facing the same issue now, how did you resolve this?

Comment: In my case I had `process.USER` instead of `process.env.USER`, so the username was returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

**try to encode your password**

- here :[encode your pass](https://www.urlencoder.org/)
- ref: [Special characters in connection string password](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection#special-characters-in-connection-string-password)

ex)

```sh
# before encode
test@#123%^
# after encode
test%40%23123%25%5E
```

this work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the username password is character encoded if you have special characters in it like @!: etc or used MongoDB password generator
See:
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes if your MongoDB User contains any special characters
Try removing any special character from the password

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it turns out I had a space in the connection string, which was hard to see in the small text input field that Heroku provides for config parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced the same issue and I did these steps it got worked for me!

1. Goto your monogoDB database (website).
2. Change the user password to automatically generated password.
3. Paste that auto generated password in the URI string.
4. Check the URI once and twice and confirm it and run the app in shell.

Answer (score 2):

I think your password may contain & or ? (or may special characters) so u should remove it, cause parsing error

Answer (score 1):

This error message typically occurs when you're trying to connect to a MongoDB database using an invalid connection string.
The password you used contains any special characters which cause parsing error which further restrict the reading of  other components  like hostname, domain name and tld.
Here's what each component represents:

- mongodb:// is the protocol used for MongoDB connections.
- username:password is the username and password for the MongoDB database, if
  authentication is required.
- host is the hostname or IP address of the server running MongoDB.
- port is the port number that MongoDB is listening on (usually 27017).
- database is the name of the database you want to connect to.
  If your password contain any special character like-

  mongodb+srv://debendra8:**Debendra@123**@cluster0.f90gm67.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
  The Field in Bold letter is Password field and is contain special character @.
  Check your respective UTF-8 format and replace it from this [**url**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)
  [image]

So Now my password would be-

```
mongodb+srv://debendra8:Debendra%40123@cluster0.f90gm67.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Now this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert the special characters (: / ? # [ ] @) in your password or username to percentange characters i.e

@ = %40
' = %27
! = %21
others
```

e.g. p@ssw0rd'9'! becomes p%40ssw0rd%279%27%21

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved it by these steps in MongoDB Compass:-

1. Click On "***Fill in connection fields individually***"

[image: Fill in connection fields individually]

2. fill your **Username** and **password**

[image: fill your Username and password]

Click on ***Connect***

Answer (score 0):

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.qjasz.mongodb.net/database-name
```

use username and password without <>

Answer (score 0):

remove <> from username and password
and password special character is encoded using the website given below

`https://www.url-encode-decode.com/`

example :
@123Password# encoded to %40123Password%23

Answer (score 0):

> ### I was getting below error while database connection(MongoDB) in my node application:

**Error:** URI must include hostname, domain name, and tld

I found the documentation for special-characters-in-connection-string-password from official site of MongoDB: [Click  Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password)!

As If your password includes special characters, and you are using your password in a connection string URI, encode the special characters.

```
databaseURI = 'mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.jekotsl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

**Root Cause for the reported error:** I was entering plain password instead of encoding the special characters.

**Solution:** I encoded the password from [Encode to URL-encoded format](https://www.urlencoder.org/) , then DB connection was succeeded.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Prior to version 3, the library expected properties to be prefixed with `env.`. The default behaviour going forward is to not use a prefix. If you require a prefix, then you can provide one like this:

`prefix=env.`

Answer (score -1):

```js
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://username:password@mernstack-pagination.dmkoc.mongodb.net/databaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority"


//db
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("DB ERROR => ", err));
```