# MongoDB Docker URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to my local MongoDB Database that is on docker with nodejs. My component are:

**.env file**

```
MONGODB_USERNAME = 'accountUser'
MONGODB_PASSWORD = 'password'
MONGODB_HOST = 'mongodb'
MONGODB_DATABASE = 'mydb'
```

**Code:**

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGODB_HOST}/${process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

    console.log(uri);

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

**Console Output**

```
mongodb+srv://accountUser:abc123@mongodb/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**Error**

```
MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705563/5589405

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to use an SRV URI when you should be using an ordirary URI.

SRV URIs have the additional security requirements on hostnames (that it contains 3 components minimum).

Remove `+srv` from your URI.

Comment: the `+srv` URI is auto-generated by mongodb atlas. is there a way to get a version without the `+srv`?

Comment: Yes, use the one for older drivers in the UI.

Comment: thank you after many many hours I managed to figure that out. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

1). Go to the database, click edit password and generate a new password.
2). Go to the database, click edit password and give only characters and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If the username or password includes the following characters:

`:` `/` `?` `#` `[` `]` `@`

You should simply replace those characters.

Answer (score 0):

How to connect to MongoDB Atlas from a NestJS Application:

1. Under `Deployment` select `Databases`
2. Click on your database instance
3. Next to the name and status of the instance click `Connect`
4. Click `Connect your application`
5. Under `DRIVER` select `Node.js`
6. Under `VERSION` select `2.2.12 or later`
7. Copy the full URI including all of the individual nodes and use that to connect instead

As `D. SM` said earlier you can't use a URI with `+srv` in it and rolling back the driver version is the only way to get a connection string generated without `+srv`.